# The second column is stretched while exporting data to pdf using DomPDF in laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf

I'm using **DomPDF** in a Laravel project. It prints well, but it stretches the second column image. **I need both columns to occupy half of the available spaces**.  I'm going to share my codes hereafter.

CSS Files:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #656262;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 570px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    /* margin-left: 90px; */
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(12, 12, 12);
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.price {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.second {
    page-break-after: always;
}

.page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.name {
    width: 82%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    font-size: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #2690ed;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    border: solid #ebe4e4 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    right: 50px;
    left: 15px;
    border: solid #ebe4e4 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.price {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: rgb(230, 83, 83);
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    border: solid #ebe4e4 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 8px;
}

.quantity {
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 30%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: rgb(243, 7, 7);
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    border: solid #ebe4e4 2px;
}

.SKU {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #60e00a !important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 8px;
}

.item-number {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: gray;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    border: solid #ebe4e4 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

This is my blade code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {{-- <link href="{{ asset('css/print.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path('/css/print.css')}}"> 
    <title>Unique Natural LLC</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header style="display:inline';overflow:inherit ">
        <p style="margin-top:2px;font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold">Unique Natural LLC</p>
    </header>
    <div class="page">
        <table>
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i += 2)
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="image"
                                    src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path('images/' . $products[$i]->image))) }}">
                                {{-- <p class="quantity"> Out Of stock  </p> --}}
                                <P class="name">{{ $products[$i]->name }}</P>
                                <p class="price">Price : {{ $products[$i]->price }} $</p>
                                <p class="SKU"> SKU : {{ $products[$i]->SKU }} </p>

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="card second">
                                <img class="image"
                                    src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path('images/' . $products[$i + 1]->image))) }}"
                                    alt="Denim Jeans">
                                <P class="name">{{ $products[$i + 1]->name }}</P>
                                <p class="item-number"> Item Number: : {{ $products[$i + 1]->item_number }}</p>

                                <p class="price">Price : {{ $products[$i + 1]->price }} $</p>
                                <p class="SKU">SKU: {{ $products[$i + 1]->SKU }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            @endfor
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And fianally I'm going to share a screen shot of the output:

[image]

Comment: You can try to set the width of `.card` to 50%: `width: 50%`. This might however cause other unwanted effects. Notice that a table should only have one table body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Size of the images you put in the `<td>` tags of the table may be different, you need to define a specific size for the `<td>` tag to handle this issue.

For example, to have the same space between two columns, you can assign a 50% width for `<td>` to make them have the same size:

```
td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

if you want to divide the space between more than 2, just divide the 100 by the number of columns you want.

Answer (score 1):

add CSS class for td.

```
td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Other thing to try with td width, is

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Might work as well. Code was a bit hard to read, but i think these will work.